# How bad is it to move the drop of a large struct to another thread?

Tags: rust, memory-management

I have a method that looks as follows:

```
fn func(
    &self,
) -> Something {
    let v: Vec<u8> = ...1mln entries...;

    ...do something with that vec...

    Something::default()
}
```

After some profiling, I realized that this function is spending around 300ms for dropping that `Vec<u8>`. I was able to measure it by doing:

```
use std::time::Instant;

...

fn func(
    &self,
) -> Something {
    let v: Vec<u8> = ...1mln entries...;

    ...do something with that vec...

    let drop_t0 = Instant::now();
    drop(v);
    println!("[drop_elapsed] {}ms", drop_t0.elapsed().as_millis());

    Something::default()
}
```

I wanted this `func` to be faster for this cleanup so I came up with the following:

```
use tokio::task;

...

fn func(
    &self,
) -> Something {
    let v: Vec<u8> = ...1mln entries...;

    ...do something with that vec...

    task::spawn(async move {
        drop(v);
    });

    Something::default()
}
```

And indeed I achieved what I wanted. I'm still a Rust newbie, so I wanted to know how bad is this. Are there other alternatives that are more idiomatic? One idea would be to make `v` as a field of the `struct` and recycle it every time, but it doesn't feel natural.

**EDIT:**

The `Vec` is not actually a `Vec<u8>`, but it's a `Vec<CustomStruct>` where:

```
pub struct CustomStruct {
    pub field: Vec<Option<Vec<u8>>>,
}
```

It's built from the response of a server. Then in the function, I do some manipulation and after that, I just don't need it anymore.

Comment: https://lib.rs/crates/defer-drop exists for this very reason, but it's still best to avoid if possible. Where is the `Vec` coming from, and how are you using it?

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode when measuring performance? I find it hard to believe that dropping the vector of integers takes so much time, and that doing it in another thread would be faster. (Even though the vector is large, dropping it doesn't require it to be traversed.)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing. I guess it could also be that the `Vec` in their actual code doesn't contain integers, and has a drop implementation. I'd suggest digging into assembly if your optimized binary is still exhibiting the issue.

Comment: Yeah indeed it's not actually a `Vec<u8>`, it's actually a `Vec<CustomStruct>`. Also, dropping it in another thread is not faster per-se, I tried to time it and it takes the same amount of time. The difference is that the method doesn't wait for that time before returning `Something`.

Comment: ah and yes, I'm compiling in release mode. I'm running it as `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run -r -p <package> --example <example-name>`

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ for pointing to `defer-drop` I didn't know it

Comment: So it's a Vec of Vecs of Vecs? What are you storing? Have you considered using a different data structure, like an [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/)?

Comment: I'm storing a table of fields, but fields are raw bytes. So it's a `Vec` (rows) of `Vec`s (columns) of `Vec`s (raw bytes), yes. And the fields could be nulls, that's why there's also an `Option` wrapping the innermost Vec.

Comment: A Vec of Vecs of Vecs will indeed take a long time just to deallocate, because each Vec has to be deallocated individually. If you can somehow change it to use a single allocation (like ndarray does), that will improve a lot. Are the number of columns in a row, or the number of bytes in a cell constant, or bounded by some upper limit?

Comment: Nit: `tokio::spawn` does not necessarily create parallelism. It only creates asynchronism/concurrency, which potentially gives you nothing in this situation. If you have a multi threaded runtime it does create some amount of parallelism; it's still not really meant for that. What you probably wanted is `spawn_blocking()`.

Comment: Adding to @PitaJ's answer: If you know the maximally possible size for your raw bytes, you can allocate it as `Option<(usize, [u8; size])>` instead. That one doesn't require an allocation and gets stored in the wrapping `Vec` directly. If you further use a single `Vec` for your rows+columns combined and address it as `x * rows + y`, you can get away with a single `Vec<Option<[u8; size]>>` allocation, which will deallocate very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that I think are important.

For one, I would consider a `drop()` function that takes 300ms as a blocking, computation-heavy task and therefore unsuited for asynchronous programming. Blocking tasks have the potential to block the executor and therefore globally block everything.

Therefore, instead of executing it in a `tokio::spawn()`, I would execute it in a [`tokio::spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), which is meant for blocking calls.

```rust
task::spawn_blocking(move || drop(v));
```

---

The second one is that you should try to avoid having such an allocation-heavy data structure in the first place. One million `Vec` allocations is a lot.

The question here is: can you combine multiple of those `Vec` allocations?

There are many alternatives:

- if they are all similar in size, use a `(usize, [u8; size])` to store a fixed-size array for each element. The `usize` is for storing how big the contained data actually is. This does not require an allocation and can directly be stored in the array. Further, you could use the size `0` for storing that it is empty, no need for an `Option`.
- if the data trickles in as continuous packets, use a stream instead of collecting it all in one data structure.
- if the data is just a bunch of brocken up parts of a larger vector, see if there is the possibility to use slices or offsets instead, and keep the actual data in the large vector.

It's hard to say for sure without knowing the exact context of your code, but maybe that created some inspiration for further optimizations.

Comment: Nice answer. I think that the, for the OP's question, the use of stream would be the way to go solution, but is still hard to ensure it without the full code there

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! This gives me a lot of inputs on how I can improve things! And yes, the stream is likely the best option since in this case I'm reading from a TCP a stream of packets.